# Data handling not working properly

Tags: java, android

I am trying to transfer data between two activities through a class which is responsible for handling data. Here are my codes:

**Home.java**

```
            String username = input.getText().toString();
        NameSave insert = new NameSave();
        insert.putString(username);
```

**NameSave.java**(handles data)

```
public class NameSave {

String gotName;

public void putString(String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    gotName=username;


}

public   String name() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return gotName;

}




     }
```

**Results.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    NameSave getName = new NameSave();
    get = getName.name();
    name.setText("Name: " + get);

}
```

Whenever I run the application, it shows " Name: null" as the result. Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Guys if it feels stupid then please dont laugh at me. I am just trying out new stuff.

Comment: Explaining the -1: Well, first things first: you should learn about Java, the conventions of JavaBeans and good practices. Although I don't expect you to be an expert in the language before try something new, but you should, at least, know a little about OOP and JavaBeans. Don't get me wrong, I'm not laughing at you, it's a constructive critic so you can be a better Java Programmer =)

Answer (score 1):

You are using two instance of the `NameSave` class. You are setting the `username` on one instance :

```
 NameSave insert = new NameSave();
 insert.putString(username);
```

And trying to retrieve it from another :

```
NameSave getName = new NameSave();
get = getName.name();
```

`insert` and `getName` are two different objects . You have to use the same instance referred by `insert` variable to get the `name` back.